# count in sql - two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have two tables:
teams(id, name) and users(id, name, team_id)

I want a following result:

```
Team  | Members 
team1 | 10 
team2 | 14 
team3 | 8
```

I tried:

```
SELECT t.name AS 'Team', COUNT(u.email) AS 'Members' FROM teams t INNER JOIN users u ON (u.team_id = t.id)
```

but it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `GROUP BY`, and you have a syntax error for alias, try this:

```
SELECT t.name AS `Team`, COUNT(u.email) AS `Members`
FROM teams t INNER JOIN users u ON (u.team_id = t.id)
GROUP BY t.name -- or t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP BY` the teams name value:

```
SELECT t.name AS `Team`, 
       COUNT(u.email) AS `Members` 
FROM teams t 
INNER JOIN users u ON u.team_id = t.id
GROUP BY t.name
```